# UV mapped texture is distorted after extruding

Tags: uv

I've got this character I built in Adobe Fuse/Mixamo imported into Blender. I wanted to put a hood on the character so I just extruded the jacket mesh up and over the head and changed out the clothing texture for this pattern, however, as you can see, the hood that I extruded is distorted, any ideas why?
[image]

Comment: Because you "*just extruded the jacket mesh up and over the head*" and never unwrapped the new parts of the mesh, nor gave it proper texture coordinates.

Comment: UV maps and their vertices are uniquely bound to the vertices in the geometry. If you create new vertices, you need to adjust the UV maps for the new vertices.